# GetStream: Only "share" an activity with certain user

Tags: getstream-io

we were fostering through the docs but couldn't find anything that would help us to implement the following feature request:

> "Privacy settings for an activity", a user wants to create an activity which is only visible to selected users in their content feed.

Our feed structure looks like this:
`User` - flat feed, and a 
`ContentFeed` - flat feed

Now, for example:

The `ContentFeed` of *user B* and *C* are following the `User` feed of *user A*. *User A* creates an activity which the user only wants to share with *user C*. After creation the activity should not appear in *user B's* `ContentFeed` but only in user *C's*.

Facebook has a similar feature, where you can select who should be able to see a post you create.

Any recommendation on how to implement this using getstream.io?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to targeting` to add activities to specific feeds in write time according to permission levels you want to support.

A adds an activity to its feed, global. If C can see it, mark its `to target` as `A-visible-C` and when `C` follows `A`, it would follow `A-visible-C`, not `A` (because it's global).

This is just a suggestion, with `to` targeting you can copy the same thing multiple places easily.

To specify it, just add `to: ["privacy:A-visible-C"]` into your activity.

Comment: Thx for the response! But then the activity gets copied, what happens if the activity updates? Will it update in the places it has been copied to? Is there any documentation reference that you can provide? Thx for taking your time!

Comment: It's same activity, you can check its id. Transparently updates. https://getstream.io/docs/targeting/?language=js

Comment: about to implement this. If I understand correctly your suggestion includes creating a new feed group called "privacy". When a user follows another user a new feed (for example A-visible-C) is being created which the user actual follows. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes. Split private and public, add activities accoridng to their level. Then, users can follow private or public according to their privacy mode.